# google-drive-ocamlfuse - slow to respond

Tags: google-drive

I installed google-drive-ocamlfuse on my ubuntu 16.04 to be able to use google drive. However, it is not very responsive. When I navigate to google drive folder and issue `ls` command it take more than 30 min to display content. Is it normal? How to troubleshoot? Are there alternative solutions?

Comment: It could be normal if it's still syncing, of course.

Comment: @MichaelBay, I have only 10 GB there and I windows machine it took me about 2 hours to sync. It has been running on Ubuntu for 12+ hours. Plus I did not see any network activity, so I am not sure what it exactly it is doing.